# Login with Facebook in a C# API

Tags: c#, facebook-login

I'm actually making an API for an application. I want my users to be able to connect to the service by using Facebook. I get the client facebook token that I post to my API. I catch the Facebook user infos I need to register my user but I don't know how to create the user from this. In particular, I don't know what to pass as argument to the first argument of "ExternalSignInAsync" (the provider). Is it a predefine value, or what I want ?

Comment: Do a bit of research on OAuth2, there should be several libraries and plugins you can work with.

Comment: you already got the token from FB. creating a new user for your service is purely on your side. You can choose whatever way to do it or you can use a 3rd party library to do it for you

Comment: My problem is more about the safety. For the moment, I create a user with a null password but I'm absolutely not sure about the security of that